# react-native-encrypted-storage:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED

Tags: react-native, detox

I am having an issue while trying to run detox build command but to be more specific it is failing on this step: `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest`, the error I am getting is here:

`Task :react-native-encrypted-storage:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED`
`app/node_modules/react-native-encrypted-storage/android/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/tempFile1ProcessTestManifest1073565797895292553.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:`
`android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>.`

Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

This is settings I have in my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
 ext {
  buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
  minSdkVersion = 28
  compileSdkVersion = 33
  targetSdkVersion = 33
  ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
  koinVersion = '3.0.1-beta-2'
  kotlinVersion = '1.6.21'
  kotlinCoroutinesVersion = "1.4.1"
  gsonVersion = "2.8.6"
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Followed some ideas but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Looks like PR needs to be merged in order to fix the issue above: https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage/pull/115